How to get C# interop DLLs to have typed arrays?
For some context, I have an old MFC COM library that the project I'm working on needs to reference. Currently, there is an old build of this library (v1.0.0) available to me via nuget (Azure feed). This was compiled by a previous developer back in 2019 and according to git history, there have been no changes to the vcxproj file since the 2019 build.
When this old build is referenced by the project I'm working on, the generated interop DLL interface has functions definitions with typed arrays (I.e., out string[]). Now when I compile it, it generates untyped arrays (out Array).
I'm at a bit off a loss at this point. Is there a specific property in the MFC project that needs to be set? It's possible that the previous dev failed to commit something like that. Given the old build works in this aspect, I don't think there is something in the project referencing it that needs to be adjusted, but is there?

Are you getting errors?  The directive "out" is equivalent to c++ point to an object.  The object could be early bindings or later bindings.  Early binding the object type is determined when compiled while Later binding the object type is determined at run time.  What is the target (Net/Core) in the vcxproj.  I suspect when you compiled the project the Net/Core library changes and updates were made to the project file.  Compare new and old project files to see differences.

No compiler errors in the mfc project. If there was a difference with the vcxproj file, the old maintainer failed to commit changes.
The C++ project is not a .net assembly and does not have a target for Net/Core. However, the C# project that references it is .net4.7

I don't know how interop assemblies are generated but I'm fairly confident that the process doesn't involve looking at native code. It probably uses .idl or .tlb descriptions. Those aren't strictly required to build the COM server and can go stale.

You are creating a c++ wrapper for you c# project.  See if following helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61968379/how-to-create-a-c-or-c-cli-wrapper-for-a-static-lib-to-use-in-c-sharp

@jdweng The OP clearly stated that they have a COM server written in native code and want to consume it from managed code.

@IInspectable : Did you look at the link?  Do you understand what a wrapper is?

@jdweng Yes, I did. That Q&A isn't about a COM server. Do you understand COM and its supporting tools and infrastructure?

@IInspectable : Why would a com server make a different in calling a DLLImport which is a window dll?  Op is calling a window dll.

@jdweng Because COM interface functions aren't exported from a module implementing said interface. You cannot DllImport, say, QueryInterface() because it isn't exported. COM servers usually only export a single function, DllGetClassObject, and that's it. This conversation would be more fruitful if both parties knew the basics.
